# WCF Receive List Of Objects and insert on database

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, listobject

I'm new on WCF webservices and I need create a method that receive one list with very clients and after insert all clients on database.

Ater some search I have this implemented

**IService.cs**

```
public interface IService1
{
   [OperationContract]
    int InsertClients(MyListofClients clients);
}

[DataContract]
public class MyListofClients
{
    [DataMember]
    List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Client
{
    [DataMember]
    public int clientId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Servic1.svc**

```
   public int InsertClients(MyListofClients clients)
    {
        int res, result;
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStringFarm))
        {
            conn.Open();
            List<MyListofClients> firstStringList = new        List<MyListofClients>();
            string cmdStr = String.Format("Insert Into table (x1,x2)" +
                                           " VALUES(@x1,@x2)");

            foreach (var item in firstStringList)
            {
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
            return 0;
           }
```

**App Client**

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click
    Dim db_comm As New NpgsqlCommand
    Dim Reader As NpgsqlDataReader


    Dim query As String = "Select code1,name1 from clientes"
    db_comm.CommandText = query
    db_comm.Connection = conn
    conn.open
    Reader = db_comm.ExecuteReader

    Dim list As New List(Of String)

    While Reader.Read
        list.Add(Reader.GetString("code1"))
        list.Add(Reader.GetString("name1"))
    End While

    Dim API As APICS.Service1Client = New APICS.Service1Client()
    API.InsertClientsAsync(list)
End Sub
```

**ERROR**
    *Value of type 'List(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'MyListofClients'.*

Someone can help me??

Thanks

Comment: This looks OK, what's your question?

Comment: Can't help you when you don't tell us what the problem is.  Do you get an error?  Does nothing happen?  How are you hosting the service?  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Now from app client in vb.net I need too pass a list for my WCF service. Basicly I need too get data from other database and send the data to this wcf in List. How I can do this??  Tim I use IIS too host and postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Your service method is expecting MyListOfClient object but you are passing list of string.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click
Dim db_comm As New NpgsqlCommand
Dim Reader As NpgsqlDataReader


Dim query As String = "Select code1,name1 from clientes"
db_comm.CommandText = query
db_comm.Connection = conn
conn.open
Reader = db_comm.ExecuteReader

Dim list As New List(Of String) -->  wrong; this should be MyListOfClient

While Reader.Read
    list.Add(Reader.GetString("code1"))
    list.Add(Reader.GetString("name1"))
End While

Dim API As APICS.Service1Client = New APICS.Service1Client()
API.InsertClientsAsyn(list) --> wrong; this should be MyListOfClient
```

Comment: but MyListOfClient its a List. what should I put there?